# Powershell List of Users and the Hosts They Rode In On

Tags: powershell

Would anybody have any suggestions?  I need to generate a list of users and the computers they're logging into, from Active Directory.  I'm hoping to get something like this:

**Username       Hostname**

*user.lastname ComputerA1*

So far, I've gotten:

> Enter-PSSession Import-Module ActiveDirectory Get-ADComputer
>   -Filter * -Properties Name Get-ADuser -filter * -Properties * | export-csv '\\\AD_UserLists.csv'

This works, kinda.  I can generate a list of computers from AD and I can generate a list of ADUsers (albeit with ALL the users information).  Unfortunately, I can't generate the data into a single CSV.

Suggestions/Advice????

Thanx,
David

Comment: You will have to run your script against each workstation when they are online. Get your OU from AD, run a foreach loop on each object with -searchbase, and grab either the most common logged in user, or the currently logged in user. There are event log and WMI methods to get either of these. I will provide an answer tomorrow if you don’t have one. For now, that is what you will need to do.

Comment: You can use Invoke-Command in your foreach loop and throw the result in an empty array. Set up a try/catch block and IF you can ping the machine (Test-Connection -computername $obj.name -Count 1 -Quiet)...if true, invoke command and run your query. If not, pass a different result to your array. The -Quiet switch will return true or false for the result of Test-Connection.

Comment: Thank  you for the advice.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: I saw it but wasn't able to get it to work - largely because of my own failings and lack of powershell knowledge.  I did find a work around though.  Needed to use a couple different systems to pull the data and merge it into a single Excel spreadsheet.  Kludgy as all get out, but in the end, management got the info they needed and I got more work. Thank you for the help and assistance.  I'll probably come back to this post at a later time when a similar problem arises.

Comment: Did you see my actual answer or just these comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the wmi function

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "computersname" | Select-Object Name,Username
```

Comment: Damn!  Wish I saw this earlier.  It's exactly what I need.  Now to remember how to create a variable to read from a list of host workstations.  :)

Comment: David, if you look through my answer, the command you accepted as the answer is in it. It will get you the currently logged in user, but that’s it. You could poll a workstation and get no information, whereas my answer tells you who logs into a computer most often, as well. It also answers your question about variables and lists of computers. In my example they come from AD, which is where I thought you were getting them from

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to get what you want. You will have to run this against AD-Computer objects when the machines are online, and catch the names of the computers you could not reach. Something like this...

```
    #grab the DN of the OU where your computer objects are located...
    $OU = ("OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com")

    #put your filtered results in $computers (I filtered for Enabled objects)...
    $computers = @()

    ForEach ($O in $OU) {

        $computers += Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $O -filter 'Enabled -eq "True"' -Properties CN,distinguishedname,lastLogonTimeStamp | Select-Object CN,distinguishedname,lastLogonTimeStamp

    }

    #instantiate some arrays to catch your results
    #collected user info
    $userInfo = @()
    #computers you cannot ping
    $offline = @()
    #computers you can ping but cannot establish WinRM connection
    $winRmIssue = @()

    #iterate over $computers list to get user info on each...
    ForEach ($computer in $computers) {

    #filter out System account SIDs
    $WQLFilter = "NOT SID = 'S-1-5-18' AND NOT SID = 'S-1-5-19' AND NOT SID = 'S-1-5-20'" 

    $WQLFilter = $WQLFilter + " AND NOT SID = `'$FilterSID`'"

    #set number of login events to grab
    $newest = 20     

        #attempt to ping computer once by name. return 'true' is success...
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer.CN -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop -Quiet) {

        #if ping is true, try to get some info...
            Try {

        #currently logged in user...
                $user = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer.CN | select -ExpandProperty username

        #the most commonly logged in user, based on the past 20 log-ins...
                $UserProperty = @{n="User";e={((New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).ToString()}}
                $logs = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer.CN -newest $newest | select $UserProperty
                $freqent = $logs | Group User | Sort-Object Count | Select -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

                }

        #catch any connection issues...
            Catch {

                $cantInvoke = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{

                'Computer' = $computer.CN
                'Message' = "Could not Invoke-Command. Probably a WinRM issue."            

                }

                $winRMIssue += $cantInvoke

                }

        #custom psobject of gathered user info...
            $userInfoObj = New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{

                'Computer' = $computer.CN
                'LoggedInUser' = $user
                'mostCommonUser' = $frequent            

                })

                    $userInfo += $userInfoObj

                }

        #if you could not ping the computer, gather that info here in a custom object...               
        else {

             $noPing = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{

             'Computer' = $computer.CN
             'DN' = $computer.distinguishedname
             'lastLogonDate' = [datetime]::FromFileTime($computer.lastLogonTimeStamp).toShortDateString()

             }

             $offline += $noPing

             }

 #then kick out the results to csv
$userInfo | Sort-Object Computer | export-csv -Path c:\path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation

$offline | Sort-Object lastLogonDate | export-csv -Path c:\path.file2csv -NoTypeInformation

$winRmIssue | Sort-Object Computer | export-csv -Path c:\path\file3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to generate a list of users and the computers they're logging into, from Active Directory.

This information is not stored in Active Directory.  You *may* be able to retrieve this information with Active Directory auditing.  Otherwise, you'll need to poll each individual workstation.